# Weird Error when setting the source path in the "PICTURE_ELEMENT"

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1

I am trying to set the `sourceImage` to a tiff file using this code:

```
        m=1
        pic = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"PICTURE_ELEMENT" , str(m))[0]
        pic.sourceImage = r"D:\PDF\tables\{0}.tiff".format(str(m)) ##error here
```

I get this error: `IOError: Cannot set path based on current settings.`

Comment: Have you tried using another image format like `.png`?

Comment: i have tried `png` format but it gives the same error

Comment: Weird. And you're sure `D:\PDF\tables\1.png` exists? AFAICT, should work.

Comment: yes i have modified the code to look for this file `D:\PDF\tables\1.png`

Comment: Are you setting the name property of the picture element properly?  Read the Discussion section of the [ListLayoutElements](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/ListLayoutElements/00s30000003w000000/) help page...  my guess is that you are simply wanting to select the first PICTURE_ELEMENT of the page, in which you would use `pic = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "PICTURE_ELEMENT")[0]`

Comment: yes i select the picture element the above line , but the error comes from this line `pic.sourceImage = r"D:\PDF\tables\{0}.tiff".format(str(m))`

Answer (score 3):

maybe this script can help you:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env 

env.workspace = r"C:\Project"
for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
   print mxdname
   mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\\" + mxdname)
   for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "PICTURE_ELEMENT"):
       print elm.name
       if elm.name == "esd_logo1"
           elm.sourceImage = r"F:\GIS\practical_shapefile\notes\esd_logo2.jpg"
   mxd.save()
del mxd
```