# IOError trying to change PICTURE_ELEMENT sourceImage

Tags: python, arcgis-server, arcpy, geoprocessing-framework

I recently ran into this issue after I published a Geoprocessing Task to a production server. It appears to be the same problem discussed in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/76097/32605), but there is no answer posted there yet. Hopefully, sharing the details of my circumstances will allow someone to provide an answer.

My geoprocessing python code is an enhanced Web Map Print service that loads a map via the `arcpy.mapping.ConvertWebMapToMapDocument` function and either sets the `sourceImage` of a `PICTURE_ELEMENT` or moves it off of the page. The published GP Service works correctly on a development server, but returns the following error when running on the production server.

```
Unable to complete operation.
Error executing tool.: 
 Traceback (most recent call last): 
   File "<ags_folder>\PythonWebPrint.GPServer\extracted\v101\my_toolboxes\service.py", line 643, in <module> main()
   File "<ags_folder>\PythonWebPrint.GPServer\extracted\v101\my_toolboxes\service.py", line 634, in main (message, output_file, image_files) = execute(web_map_json, output_format, layout_template, layout_template2, georef_info, quality)
   File "<ags_folder>\PythonWebPrint.GPServer\extracted\v101\my_toolboxes\service.py", line 482, in execute staticLegend.sourceImage = legendPath
   File "c:\program files\arcgis\server\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\_base.py", line 87, in _set return setattr(self._arc_object, attr_name, cval(val))
  IOError: Cannot set path based on current settings.
  Failed to execute (PythonWebPrint). Failed to execute (Python Web Print).
```

I have verified that the correct file path is being used, and that the file exists and that the folder and file permissions are identical to the MXD files being loaded by the `arcpy.mapping.ConvertWebMapToMapDocument` function.

Any ideas as to the source of or how to fix this issue, or other diagnostics that I can perform?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please see [my answer on the Esri forums](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/113378-IOError-trying-to-change-PICTURE_ELEMENT-sourceImage). If the picture element in your map document is set to derive its source from a field or an attachment via Data-Driven Pages, then you cannot set its source manually.

Comment: Problem solved. The underlying issue was related to windows-specific behavior when a path includes drive letters.